# Is it possible to successfully complete several sequential (order-dependent) token transfers within 1 transaction?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, kovan

Is this an example of such?
https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x5d11fca70dd134628641bc1ce07b7185418748e5e9820b45b608d9526e629136

[image: Potential example:]

Might using inline assembly allow for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you wrote a contract with a function which calls several transfer functions on several other token contracts, you could do this with one transaction.

But you'd have to provide enough gas to that one function to cover all the transfers.

Comment: How might one ensure these calls to transfer functions are executed in order?  
(While still executing in the same block)

Comment: There's nothing to ensure. The code executes in order. It will all be part of the same transaction.